# Intellij throws NoClassDefFoundError when run test files

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

The test files run on Eclipse with no error. I opened the eclipse project on IntelliJ, configured the SDK, and marked the test folder as the green test source folder. However, when I run the test files on IntelliJ, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

**Test File**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import interviewCakeSolutions.appleStockPro1Solution;
import org.junit.Test;

public class appleStockPro1SolutionTester {

      @Test
      public void testGivenInput() {
          int[] testInput = new int[] {10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9};
          int actual = appleStockPro1Solution.getMaxProfit(testInput);
          int expected = 6;
          assertEquals(expected, actual);
      }
}
```

**InterviewCakeSolution.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/bin" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library name="junit4">
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/lib/junit-4.12.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

**Project Directory**
[image]

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Could you please include the stacktrace?

Comment: Do you only get that stacktrace in your run console, or the tests are also failing?

Comment: @Mureinik added stack trace to bottom of my question

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy yes, I get the stacktrace in my run console. The tests are not running

Comment: As the error shows, you need to add hamcrest (hamcrest-core 1.3, as the pom shows: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12) to the classpath, since JUnit relies on it. The install guide of JUnit also explains it, BTW: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. The reason was apparently that some other class in the same project (which **was not** needed for the test) had errors in it. This prevented the compiler from compiling the class which **was** needed. I solved it by changing to Eclipse compiler with *Proceed on errors* checked (Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler).

[image: screenshot]